# How to combine two tokenizers in lucene (japaneseanalyzer and standardanalyzer)

Tags: lucene

I am using lucene 4.3.0 and want to tokenize the doc with both English and Japanese characters.

```
    An example is like "LEICA S２ カタログ （新品）"
    The StandardAnalyzer "[leica] [s２] [カタログ] [新] [品]"
    The JapaneseAnalyzer "[leica] [s] [2] [カタログ] [新品]"
```

In the application of my project, the StandardAnalyzer is better on English characters, e.g. [s２] is better than [s] [2]. JapaneseAnalyzer is better on Japanese, e.g.  [新品] to  [新] [品]. In addition, JapaneseAnalyzer has a good feature to convert fullwidth character "２" to "2".

```
    If I want the tokens to be [leica] [s2] [カタログ] [新品], it means:
    1) English and numbers are tokenized by StandardAnalyzer. [leica] [s2]
    2) Japanese are tokenized by JapaneseAnalyzer. [カタログ] [新品]
    3) fullwidth character are converted to halfwidth by a filter. [s２]=>[s2]
    how to implement this custom analyzer?
```

Comment: I know it has been a while, but were you able to achieve the behavior you were looking for somehow?

Answer (score 3):

First thing I would try is messing with the arguments passed to the [JapaneseAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-kuromoji/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/JapaneseAnalyzer.html#JapaneseAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.JapaneseTokenizer.Mode,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet,%20java.util.Set%29), particularly the [Tokenizer.Mode](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-kuromoji/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/JapaneseTokenizer.Mode.html) (I know precisely nothing about the structure of the Japanese language, so no help from me on the intent of those options).

---

Barring that

You'll need to create your own Analyzer for this.  Unless you are willing to write your own Tokenizer, the end result may be a best effort.  Creating an analyzer is pretty simple, creating a tokenizer will mean defining your own grammar, which will not be so simple.

Take a look at the code for [JapaneseAnalyzer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-kuromoji/4.0.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/JapaneseAnalyzer.java#JapaneseAnalyzer.createComponents%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.io.Reader%29) and [StandardAnalyzer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.1.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java#StandardAnalyzer.createComponents%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.io.Reader%29), particularly the call to `createComponents`, which is all you need to implement to create a custom analyzer.

Say you come to conclusion the `StandardTokenizer` is correct for you, but otherwise we're going to use mostly the Japanese filter set, it might look something like:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    //For your Tokenizer, you might consider StandardTokenizer, JapaneseTokenizer, or CharTokenizer
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(version, reader);
    TokenStream stream = new StandardFilter(version, tokenizer);
    stream = new JapaneseBaseFormFilter(stream);
    stream = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, stream);  //In JapaneseAnalyzer, a lowercasefilter comes at the end, further proving I don't know Japanese.
    stream = new JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilter(true, stream, stoptags);
    stream = new CJKWidthFilter(stream);  //Note this WidthFilter!  I believe this does the char width transform you are looking for.
    stream = new StopFilter(matchVersion, stream, stopwords);
    stream = new JapaneseKatakanaStemFilter(stream);
    stream = new PorterStemFilter(stream); //Nothing stopping you using a second stemmer, really.
    return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, stream);
}
```

That's a completely random implementation, from someone who doesn't understand the concerns, but hopefully it points the way toward implementing a more meaningful Analyzer.  The order in which you apply filters in that filter chain are important, so be careful there (ie. In english, LowerCaseFilter is usually applied early, so that things like Stemmers don't have to worry about case).